# How can I constraint a type if use element ref as an input value of a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have tried codes like this, but it seems T should have some constraints which I am not clear.

```
export const useResizeObserver = <T>(elementRef: ElementRef<T>, debounceTimeout = 100) => {}
```

Comment: Could you add more context ? I don't understand the problem

Answer (score 1):

These are the restraints for what `T` you can pass to an `ElementRef`, from [the React typings](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/2a4cb89b6fe4913719272464870240a9d38a83e5/types/react/index.d.ts#L111):

```
T extends
            | ForwardRefExoticComponent<any>
            | { new (props: any): Component<any> }
            | ((props: any, context?: any) => ReactElement | null)
            | keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements
```

It can be any `ComponentType` (`FunctionComponent` or `ClassComponent`), a built-in DOM element like `div`, and some other complicated things.